# Calling python functions from command prompt with arguments and capturing the return values in GDB

Tags: python, gdb

The tried the below python script(I call it sample.py).It does the lookup on a c++ code in GDB

```
import gdb
def getstring():
    string = "RandomSearchString"
    value = gdb.lookup_symbol(string)
    print("string %s is at sym %s" %(string, value))
```

It works perfectly fine. But I want to know if I have the code something like below how do I call the function getstring from outside the code in gdb.

```
import gdb
def getstring(string):
    string = "%s" %(string)
    value = gdb.lookup_symbol(string)
    return value
```

I do the below execution steps in GDB

```
g++ -g cppcode.cpp -o cppcode
gdb ./cppcode
run
<<gives a seg fault and haults>>
source sample.py
```

After this point I should be able to call the function as getstring(RandomSearchString) and store the return value somewhere.

Any suggestions on how to do it because when I do

```
var x = getstring(RandomSearchString)
```

It gives me error saying x not in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do using convenience variables and pretty printers.